Active internet connection, but cannot apt-get update
Trying to figure out why I can't update ubuntu 24.04.1. I can ping other sites, wget various websites, but I cannot update.
apt-get update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu noble InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                                                                    
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                                                                    
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease          
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease          
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4002:1::101). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) 
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I had to remove a lot of output because the form submission said "This looks like spam"
wget cars.com
--2024-10-13 18:19:11--  http://cars.com/
Resolving cars.com (cars.com)... 54.80.177.85, 3.93.126.98
Connecting to cars.com (cars.com)|54.80.177.85|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.cars.com/ [following]
--2024-10-13 18:19:12--  https://www.cars.com/
Resolving www.cars.com (www.cars.com)... 23.213.70.34
Connecting to www.cars.com (www.cars.com)|23.213.70.34|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                                      [ <=>                                                                                      ] 812.21K  --.-KB/s    in 0.07s   

2024-10-13 18:19:20 (12.1 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [831705]

wget ubuntu-mirror-2.ps6.canonical.com
--2024-10-13 18:19:24--  http://ubuntu-mirror-2.ps6.canonical.com/
Resolving ubuntu-mirror-2.ps6.canonical.com (ubuntu-mirror-2.ps6.canonical.com)... 91.189.91.82, 2620:2d:4002:1::102
Connecting to ubuntu-mirror-2.ps6.canonical.com (ubuntu-mirror-2.ps6.canonical.com)|91.189.91.82|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to ubuntu-mirror-2.ps6.canonical.com (ubuntu-mirror-2.ps6.canonical.com)|2620:2d:4002:1::102|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.

